Express Multer breaking deployments but working locally
I have an express api that uses Multer for image uploading. I am running to the error Namespace 'global.Express' has no exported member 'Multer'.
I had a similar issue locally and I solved it with the following.
Package.json
"devDependencies: {
    ...,
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",
    ...
}

TSConfig
{
    "types": ["jest", "node", "express", "Multer"]
}

I also have a types.d.ts file at the root of my project with the following
import { Details } from 'express-useragent'

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            useragent?: Details
            ipAddress?: string
        }
    }
}


Now when I go to deploy my project I am getting the following
Cannot find type definition file for 'Multer'. 
Namespace 'global.Express' has no exported member 'Multer'.
I have gone to my server, cleared cache and redeployed a few times with no success. I even moved the types from devDependencies to dependencies with no luck.
Anybody run into the same situation when deploying to a live server?

Did you ever figure this out?

I eventually found a thread that discussed this error and I believe all I did was change versioning in my package.json. Unfortunately I cant remember where any of this conversation took place as I dont get this error anymore, sorry mate
